# Como usar BindProperty em variáveis em que os nomes são dinâmicos em .net-core razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Em asp.net core razor pages para passar dados de um formulário declaro da seguinte forma:

```
[BindProperty]
public int NMembro1 { get; set; }
```

Sendo que do lado do formulário a tag `input` está declarada da seguinte forma:

```
<input style="max-width:5.75rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px;" name="NMembro1' type="number" min="1">
```

Então percebo que o atributo `name` da tag `input` tem o mesmo nome que a variável no backend. `name="NMembro1'`

```
 [BindProperty]
  public int NMembro1 { get; set; }
```

Após o enquadramento passo a explicar o problema:

Esta tag input é criada dinamicamente em[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), então para conseguir obter os dados da `view` preciso de declarar estas variáveis de forma dinamica.

Segue abaixo o código [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```
 let html = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
 {
   html += '<input style="max-width:5.75rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px;" name="NMembro' + i +'" type="number" min="1">';
 }
```

Algo que funcionou foi declarar as variáveis na seguinte forma:

```
[BindProperty]
public int NMembro1 { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public int NMembro2 { get; set; }

...
```

Mas o problema continua: **Se não sei quantas variaveis são geradas em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) como consigo declara-las desta forma do lado do [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)?**

Após ler alguma documentação tentei algo deste tipo

```
 [BindProperty]
 public Dictionary<string, object> NMembro { get; set; }
```

Mas nao ajudou em nada pois continuei sem conseguir fazer bidding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[BindProperty] 
public List<string> NMembro { get; set; }
```

Os dados estão a ser gerados usando [javasript](/questions/tagged/javasript) assim sendo, os dados depois de gerados são colocados com [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para manipular e gerar o [html](/questions/tagged/html), no entanto esta minha referência ao [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) serve apenas de enquadramento para a pergunta em questão.

Segue abaixo o código [javasript](/questions/tagged/javasript)

```
    let html = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++;)
    {
       html += '<input style="max-width:5.75rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px;"
       name="' + NMembro[i]+'" type="number" min="1">'
    }
```

**Explicação final**

O problema ocorria porque precisavamos de fazer bind de uma propriedade e o nome dessa propriedade era gerado em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```
 NMembro[i]
```

Então para o `[BindProperty]` funcionar do lado do lado do servidor declaramos a variável com o tipo `List` da seguinte forma `public List<string> NMembro { get; set; }`

Deixo agora por fim uma referência útil que encontrei na internet para responder a esta pergunta
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/model-binding-asp-net-core/